# What to pass to form_for when using an explicitly specified controller in the resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for

I have specified a controller to use in my resource:

```
resources :blog, controller: 'posts'
```

And now I need to create an input form to create a new post/blog using form_for.
If my resource was simply resources:posts, then I would use

```
<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
```

But clearly, this doesn't work.
I am looking to answer the question: what object/name do I need to pass into form_for in order to make it compatible with my specified controller.

Comment: I don't really understand why you would use the `posts_controller` to create `Blog` records? Why not split into two distinct controllers?

Comment: Why do you want to change the controller like this out of interest? Why not put the posts route within a blog namespace for example? Custom routes like this mean the simple helpers like form_for don't work, you have to explicitly add the url to the form tag

Comment: The answers below will work, but your routes don't make a lot of sense.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I'll look into a cleaner option. I ended up here because I want a posts resource not a blog resource. And I want routes that are /blog/my-blog-name rather than /blog/posts/my-blog-name.

Answer (score 1):

You can re-write the default path of the `form_for`:

```
form_for(@post, url: your_helper_path) do |f|
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify URL i.e. blog's URL.

```
<%= form_for(@post, :url => blog_url) do |f| %>
```

P.S.: You should re-think about your routes. I don't understand why you are merging `post` and `blog`.